# Regression using mean repeated measurements

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, experiment-design, measurement

I would like to know what is the best way for determining the relationship between 2 (or more) variables: one (or more) independent that is (are) set on the measuring device, and a dependent variable that is the output measurement which has some fluctuation. I am aware that the question is rather basic and silly: what is the optimal way to acquire measurements? I am asking because for the case of 1 independent variable, a collaborator likes to acquire 5 repeated measurements for 5 independent variable values, then takes the mean of each value and does a linear regression on those 5 mean values. In my view, the appropriate approach is to rather acquire 1 measurement for 25 different independent variable values. And this would be more powerful when the relationship between multiple independent variables is examined (i.e. 1 measurement for many combinations of independent variables' values rather than the mean of repeated measurements for few combinations). Of course, combining both approaches would be even better...

What do you think?

Comment: It all depends on exactly what you mean by "better."  For instance (continuing your example), if by "better" you mean *lowest possible standard errors in the estimated coefficients* and there is just one explanatory variable, then the optimal solution takes 12 measurements at one extreme of that variable and the other 13 measurements at the other extreme!  Could you therefore elaborate on what *you* mean by "better," "best," "optimal," and "more powerful"?

Comment: All those words intend to say "provide the most precise determination of the relationship between variables". By "powerful" I was referring to the statistical power of regression, but I am not a mathematician so please consider me as a novice. In general, I would ask how would YOU acquire the measurements in order to examine the relationship between two or more variables? For how many values of independent variables you would acquire measurements? And how many (if any) repeated measurements for each? And would you use all repeated measurements in the regression, or their mean?

Comment: Hi again whuber. Apologies if I made things even less clear. Let's assume that "better" means lowest possible standard errors in the estimated coefficients, as you indicated. What would in this case be the correct approach for one or two explanatory variables?

Comment: The optimal solution in that sense would be the one I mentioned.  People rarely use it, though, because typically we need to check the model assumptions.  Therefore additional measurements are made at intermediate points to check goodness of fit.  In multiple regression there is more than one estimate of interest, which complicates the meaning of "better".  Please read the Wikipedia article on [optimal design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_design) for an overview.

Comment: That makes sense. To follow up, for a single variable regression, I plotted all measurements (5 points with 3 repeated measurements each) and got an R squared of 0.93, then I plotted only the mean values of the repeated measurements (5 points) and R^2 increased to 0.98, as expected. While the regression equation was exactly the same, the increase in the R^2 seemed inappropriate to me (i.e. cheating!). So, for determining the proportion of the variance in the dependent variable that is predictable from the independent variable, do you think the 2nd approach is acceptable?